# Can we create Temp Tables in File Storage, Not in Memory

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

My data set is too large (about 12 million records) to query. I need to fetch that much amount of data for intermediate calculations. If I use Temp tables, which causes a huge memory consumption.

Is there any mechanisms in SQL Server 2008 R2 onward, which can create temp tables, not in memory, in disk ?

Comment: `tempdb` is real and is backed by a real file. temp tables *will* go to disk. (But SQL Server will prefer to keep hot data in memory rather than leaving memory empty)

Comment: Can't you split the 12 million records in batches and process them separately?

Comment: In fact, it used to be a common *myth* that temp tables went in tempdb and were thus file based and table variables were in-memory only.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare table like variable

```
declare @table ...
```

It is stored in memory.
To store it in db file create temporary table like normal table with # prefix for only your session or ## prefix for all sessions like this:

```
CREATE table #TMP (
   name nvarchar(20)
   ....
)
```

You can create it automaticly doing something like this:

```
select id, name, something_else into #TMP from your_phisical_table
```

Comment: As I commented below the question, this memory vs file difference between table variables vs temp tables is a **myth**. I'd hoped it had expired by now, but apparently not. Both types store data in tempdb and may occupy disk space.

Comment: E.g., from [Faster temp table and table variables by using Memory Optimization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/faster-temp-table-and-table-variable-by-using-memory-optimization#d-scenario-table-variable-can-be-memoryoptimizedon): "A traditional table variable represents a table in the tempdb database. For much faster performance you can memory-optimize your table variable."

Comment: Both @table and #TMP are created in tempdb, so +1 to Damien_The_Unbelieve